# While solving the motion in plane problems (dynamics) how to figure out whether the radial accelration is 0 or mgsin(theta)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, nonlinear-dynamics, arithmetic-dynamics

There is a problem : A straight smooth tube revolves with constant angular velocity W in a horizontal plane about one extremity which is fixed. If at zero time the tube be horizonal and a particle inside it be at a distance a from the fixed end and moving with velocity along the tube, find the distance at time t.

Now a similar problem is solved by taking the radial acceleration 0. But this problem has been solved taking the radial acceleration as -g sin Wt. The final answers also came different. Please help me in figuring out how to choose the radial acceleration in such problems.

Comment: This is more physics than math.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the second formula you suggested holds for motion in a vertical plane under the influence of gravity. The radial acceleration would not have varied as a simple harmonic equation in case the motion was horizontal as g holds constant at a given height. But it seems some more info is required as radial acceleration in such cases can never be zero. Circular motion necesitates the presence of centripetal force and non-inertial centrifugal force., the second of which might result in displacement should there be no string or anything to hold the object to.